# Problems overriding a property to null in Spring bean declaration

Tags: spring, overriding, javabeans

Just wondering if there is a way in Spring to have a parent controller:

```
<bean id="parentController" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.SimpleFormController" abstract="true">
     <property name="validator" ref="validatorImpl"/>  
     ...
</bean>
```

, and a class extending it:

```
<bean id="child1Controller" class="com.portlet.controller.Child1Controller" parent="parentController">
   <property name="validator"><null/></property>
     ...
</bean>

<bean id="child2Controller" class="com.portlet.controller.Child2Controller" parent="parentController"> 
     ...
</bean>
```

, in such a way that the child overrides a property to null.

I know if you don't declare the property in either the parent or the child, you get the wanted effect, but as in most of the places validator refers to validatorImpl, I thought as a inheritance principle, I would be able to override a property to null.

I keep getting:

15:29:50,141 ERROR [PortletHotDeployListener:534] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'childController' defined in PortletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/sugerencia-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'childController' defined in PortletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/sugerencia-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

On the other hand,

```
 <bean id="parentController" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.SimpleFormController" abstract="true">
  ...
</bean>

 <bean id="child1Controller" class="com.portlet.controller.Child1Controller" parent="parentController">
     ...
</bean>

 <bean id="child2Controller" class="com.portlet.controller.Child2Controller" parent="parentController">
    <property name="validator" ref="validatorImpl"/> 
     ...
</bean>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing what `ParentController` is, we've no way of helping

Comment: Why do u need to know what ParentController is??

Comment: Because you're injecting a null into it, and we're not psychic.

Comment: Is that clearer now, or you need more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly setting a property to `<null/>` isn't the same as not setting it. The property's setter method may check that the value you're injecting is non-null, for example.

If you look at the source code for `BaseCommandController` (which is a superclass of your controller), you'll see that `setValidator` does no such checking. However, when the bean is initialized in `initApplicationContext()`, it iterates over the array of validators, assuming they're all non-null, and will throw a NPE if there's a null in that array, which if likely what's happening here.

Unfortunately, there is no way to "unset" a property that has been configured in a parent bean definition. You'll need to rearrange the definitions so that the parent doesn't set it.

Comment: I agree with u, but that's a pain in the neck!!

Comment: As u said it seems that the NPE is the result of calling this.validators[i].supports(this.commandClass) (What returns null) after calling setValidator (null)

public final void setValidator(Validator validator) {
                this.validators = new Validator[] {validator};
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `parent` you are either using the `validator` in either `setter` method or in `afterPropertiesSet`. That may be the reason for the `NPE`. Check it once, if you are not using the `validator` which in your case is null anywhere in the initialization phases in your parent class, it should work fine.

Comment: That's not the problem, as I stated, declaring it neither in the parent nor in the child cause any problem.